# How To share/manage Typescript Types between Frontend and Backend In Big Projects

Tags: javascript, typescript, mern, directory-structure

I have a MERN project with the following folder structure.

backend is an express,mongo backend. With the following structure.

frontend is folder of 3 vite react projects. each has the following folder structure

```
Parent Folder:
- backend
    - src
        - controllers 
        - middlewares
        - models
        - schemas
        - types
        - utils
        - app.ts
        - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
- frontend
    - client  (this is a vite app)
        - src
            - assets
            - components
            - hooks
            - pages
            - screens
            - types
        - index.html
        - package.json
        - tsconfig.json
    - master  ( this is also same as client)
    - manager (this is also same as client)
```

In this implementation i have created a Types folder in each of the folders.

**backend**,

**frontend/client**,

**frontend/master**,

**frontend/manager**

So everytime someone pushes a new change in the type of one thing. i have to change it in all the 4 folders so that they are the same.

**MY QUESTION IS:**

I want to find a way to declare the Types globally in the Parent Folder so that i am able to use them anywhere in backen or the 3 frontends i want.

The types i want to make global is mainly database document schema which are reused a lot everywhere.

Right now how i am managing the types is by manually copying and pasting regularly. This causes a lot of problem if the types are changing frequently.

**Is there a way to do this better??**

Comment: This is a common scenario when you use typescript for the full stack. You have two ways to do that. Your shared types may be in a separate npm package (in) to use the Monorepo approach. The npm package could be a direct link to the git repository.

Comment: I am not for sure here, neither have I tried this before, but I think it would be possible to use a symlinked file in the frontends that just links back to one type declaration file?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a mono repo architecture and tools for managing a single code base. A good example is something like nx.dev for handling monorepos.